# NodeJS WriteStream

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am learning the NodeJS WriteStream. I cannot understand the effect of the `res.end()` function call bellow. What would happen if the `res.end()` call did not exists in the following example? I removed that, but did not any change and in both case the result returned to the client.

```
const fs = require("fs");
const server = require("http").createServer();

server.on("request", (req, res) => {
  const readable = fs.createReadStream("test-file.txt");
  readable.on("data", (chunk) => {
    res.write(chunk);
  });

  // Is the following piece of code really needed?
  readable.on("end", () => {
    res.end();
  });
});

server.listen(8000, "127.0.0.1", () => {
  console.log("Listening...");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In some scenarios the res.end is used to end the response , as it says , otherwise it would never stop.

And it may be used if the data being read is large , with async functions that need time to be executed , or with shell scripts with exports etc ..